# How can I access an API's object that has an integer as index

Tags: javascript, html, api

How do you access an API's response with an integer as its object, example data.results.0;
When I try this, it brings up an error in my console log of (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number)... please help...

This is the response i get from the API server;

```
Object {  
    currency: "USD"  
}  
results: Array[1] {   
    0: Object  
}
```

I am trying to access the 0; but when i do the following in my code; data.results.0. i get the error above.

Comment: Well you'll need to clarify so much more.

Comment: Take a look at this manual:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can access an object placed in an numeric index (i.e. integer) the following way:

```
var firstResult = data.results[0];
```

This works both for objects and arrays.

If the index is a number but a string instead of an integer, you can access it this way:

```
var firstResult = data.results['0'];
```

This method only works *correctly* for objects. It does work for arrays as well, but arrays are intended to only have integer-based indexing, so it would really be a bad practice.

Comment: I have been able to access, the object. However now I am trying to identify the length of the object, and trying to get the javascript to print out "Yes" when the length is greater than 1 else "No". My code looks like this;

Comment: var i=1 
    if (i<data.results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].length){
           console.log("Yes")
          }
i have looked online but still go no clue

Comment: Your code seems correct; are you sure the flights variable is an Array and not an object? What length are you getting with this code?

Comment: it looks like it is an array; (flights:Array[2]) and with the current code i am not getting anything just doesn't print anything out in the console

Comment: Then just say `var flightsNo = data.results[0].itineraries[0].outbound.flights[0].length;
console.log("No of flights: " + flightsNo);` and let us know what do you get.